# Python Flask/ReactJS/React Router, Heroku Deployment API call not working for GCP

Tags: python, reactjs, heroku

I have an app that is deployed to Heroku that uses gunicorn as the Procfile and has a Python flask backend that manages pushing the frontend with `send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'index.html')` and API calls such as

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
      return loginUser(request.form['email'], request.form['password'])
```

I have a connect file that looks like:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from mysql.connector.constants import ClientFlag

config = {
    'user': 'root',
    'password': 'password',
    'host': 'ip',
    'database': 'name',
    'client_flags': [ClientFlag.SSL],
    'ssl_ca': 'ssl/server-ca.pem',
    'ssl_cert': 'ssl/client-cert.pem',
    'ssl_key': 'ssl/client-key.pem'
}

def connectToDB():
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
        if connection.is_connected():
            return connection
        return False
    except:
        return False
```

I can connect to the database locally through the API call, but when it is run on the server it does not work. I usually get the "Something went wrong" statement from this code

```
def loginUser(email, password):
    try:
        connection = connectToDB()
        if(connection != False):
            cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

            if(invalidEmail(email, cursor, connection)):
                return {"response": "No account with that Email"}
            
            userId = getId(email, password, cursor, connection)
            connection.commit()
            cursor.close()
            if(userId == -1):
                return {"response": "Incorrect Password"}

            return {"response": "Success",
                    "id": userId}
            # need to return ID
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        return {"response": err.msg }
    
    return {"response": "Something went wrong"}
```

I have tried adding the Fixie extension to heroku and adding the static IPs from there to the Authorised networks in the GCP relational database (also tried adding 0.0.0.0/0).

I don't get any errors in the heroku logs, it just simply can't connect when it is done on the server. I also tested the API call and it works fine in postman using the heroku project link.

Comment: After adding `return {"connection": connection}` and adding console.log(res) in the js file, I get {connection: false} output in the console of my browser

Comment: Execute your Flask app without Gunicorn. Your `connectToDB` is return `False` presumably due to Gunicorn since Gunicorn is establishing multiple DB connection. (Gunicorn runs your Flask app multiple times and does its own load balancing)

Comment: After logging the connection error, I get this: {connection: "2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '35.239.2…:3306', system error: 2 No such file or directory"}, should I just run it with web: python app.py?

Comment: @TinNguyen I get the same error, even if I execute the app with just running the python file:
{connection: "2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '35.239.2…:3306', system error: 2 No such file or directory"}connection: "2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '35.239.244.129:3306', system error: 2 No such file or directory"__proto__: Object

The Procfile is: `web: python server/myapp.py` (it is in a server folder)

Comment: Update, I think the ssl folder path was bad, but after fixing it, I still get this error even when setting the Procfile to use the above command
{connection: "2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at '35.239.2…system error: 1 [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:852)"}